# How to properly pass data to <input list> attribute?

Tags: html, google-chrome, input

I have a very simple HTML5 page:

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <label for="cmb_unit">Unit:</label>

      <input list="browsers">

      <datalist id="browsers">
        <option value="Internet Explorer">
        <option value="Firefox">
        <option value="Chrome">
        <option value="Opera">
        <option value="Safari">
      </datalist>          

      <br>
      <label for="text_description">Click here and enter 1:</label>
      <br>
      <textarea id="text_description" name="text_description"></textarea>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

(or it can be tested online here: http://jsfiddle.net/4qaxR/3/)

The problem is when I select an item from the first control ("Firefox", for example) and enter a number "1" in the next control then this `textarea` control displays data from "browsers" `datalist`. Even more, if I click on something from the list then the browser page crashes immediately (it's Chrome "35.0.1916.153 m").

Is it something wrong here?

Comment: Only thing wrong is your first `label`, its `for` attribute should refer to the `input`, not the `datalist` – but that doesn’t resolve the error. And I can reproduce Chrome crashing (well, the tab at least), when selecting a value in the list for the textarea … so browser bug, I’d say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it seems to be the issue with the browser, It is a chrome browser bug. They have fixed it in their beta release version 36, you will need to download from here https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/index.html?extra=betachannel#eula this will update your browser and the site will work smoothly...!!!

This issue had cost me 4 months of research on this issue...

Cheers..